# I want Text Editor in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a project in which i will read MS-Word file and retrieve text from the file and then provide the facility to the user to edit the text and then save it.
So i have read the file and extract text successfully using OPEN XML.
 My question is how i can put the all text in some editor(Need some editor) and when user edit or whatever he will do then how i can retrieve text from the text editor and save it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used TinyMCE in asp.net with excellent results
try it here:
http://www.tinymce.com/

Also you can use:

http://ckeditor.com/

Both will allow you to present the text with the same format, the word document has.

Comment: Can i put my text in that editor and can retrieve text from that editor into string or any other way?

Comment: Sure: read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674754/TinyMCE-and-ASP-NET-MVC-advanced-features

Comment: I am unable to use Tinymvc.
How i can use tinymcs with <textarea>?

Comment: tinymce.init({
    mode: "textareas".. see this example, is very clear  http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php